# Static libraries exporting API objects

Tags: api, static-libraries, terminology

The company I work for has multiple in-house projects and libraries.
Someone said the following

> Let's move away from static libraries exporting API objects. Then we could link only against <LIB_XXX>.

I hope that the quote is enough for someone to guess the gist of it, e.g.

- What does "move away" mean? What is an alternative?
- What does "static libraries exporting API objects" mean?
- How does the first sentence connect to "Then we could link only against"?

Comment: I guess it has to do with compiliation. Check this for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linker/

Comment: But tbh, never feel stupid for asking a question. The best thing you could do would be asking the person who said it. It's OK to not know everything. Someone willing to learn and improve is way more worth than someone who think they know it all.